# Shrinking monospace style for listings package

Tags: listings, fontsize, typewriter

I am working on a thesis and putting together a "pretty" listing. I'm looking at setting up a small font style for a code view. What I have here is:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
numberstyle=\footnotesize,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
numbers=left,
stepnumber=1,
frame=shadowbox,
breaklines=true}
%\usepackage[subsection]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
```

But this comes out in a typical kerned font, vs. I am looking for smaller monospace, say, 10 points or so.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually you should add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Then we can see what packages you are using etc. Here the `\lstset` seems to be enough, however.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the default

```
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,...
```

or better with package `microtype`

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\newcommand\Small{\fontsize{9}{9.2}\selectfont}
\newcommand*\LSTfont{\Small\ttfamily\SetTracking{encoding=*}{-60}\lsstyle}
...
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\LSTfont,...]
...
```

Which gives a better result.

Comment: Any recommendation to `LuaLaTeX` users on what to do here?

Comment: See documentation of package `microtype`

Answer (score 21):

You are missing a `\ttfamily` in the `basicstyle`. If this doesn't give you the size you want try `\scriptsize` or even `\tiny` instead of `\footnotesize`. You don't need to add the same size for the `numberstyle` again because `basicstyle` is used for everything by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
numberstyle=\footnotesize,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
numbers=left,
stepnumber=1,
frame=shadowbox,
breaklines=true}

\begin{document}
Normal text

\begin{lstlisting}
    int a, b, c;
    b = 2;
    c = b++;
    a = b + c;
\end{lstlisting}

Normal text
\end{document}
```

Comment: scriptsize worked for me, because it's between tiny and footnote size. it was the best trade off.

Answer (score 21):

The "kerned" appearance comes from the default settings of package `listings`.

### Default settings with `basicstyle=\ttfamily`

Package `listings` uses `columns=fixed` as default. It provides the best vertical alignment, as you can see the code in a mono-spaced font in an source code editor. The settings means, the character are placed in boxes of width `0.6em`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Quick alignment test: 
%   MMMM a
%   iiii a
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle  = \ttfamily,
  % basewidth = {.5em,0.5em},
  % columns   = flexible,
  % columns   = fullflexible,
}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting[
    language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
  ]{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with default settings]

### Optimized `basewidth`

The width `0.6em` for the fixed columns takes into account that wider characters should also fit into the box without overlapping the adjacent charactes. However mono-spaced fonts have already a fixed width for all
characters. The width of a character is usually `0.5em`, where the font designer has already squeezed the broader glyphs. Thus we can reduce
`basewidth` from `0.6em,0.45em` to `0.5em,0.5em`. The second value is used for `columns=flexible`. This mode does not align all characters, but words. Words usually have narrower and wider characters, thus the average is smaller than the width for the widest character. But this does not make sense for mono-spaced fonts. Smaller values than the glyph width will only disturb the vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Quick alignment test:
%   MMMM a
%   iiii a
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  basewidth  = {.5em,0.5em},
  % columns  = flexible,
  % columns  = fullflexible,
}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting[
    language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
  ]{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with optimized <code>basewidth</code>]

### Variable width typewriter font

If the vertical alignment is not too important (as in the lines of `\lstset` in the example), then a variable width typewriter font can be used. The Latin Modern fonts (further development of the Computer Modern fonts), provide such a font that can be enabled via option `variablett` of package `lmodern`. (Alternatively `\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont` could be used.)

Because setting a variable width font in fixed columns looks uglier than using a mono-spaced font, the example uses `columns=flexible`. Also the `basewidth` is reduced to `0.4em` (default is `0.45em` leaves too many gaps).

```
\documentclass{article}
% Quick alignment test:
%   MMMM a
%   iiii a
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  basewidth  = {.5em,0.4em},
  columns    = flexible,
  % columns  = fullflexible,
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting[
    language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
  ]{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with lmvtt and flexible columns]

- Drawback of the flexible columns settings is that the vertical alignment inside the lines might get lost. The line indenting works, however.
- As additional advantage the Latin Modern fonts provides a bold version (also in the mono-spaced variante).

### Variable width typewriter font with full flexible columns

And now the example with setting `columns=fullflexible`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Quick alignment test:
%   MMMM a
%   iiii a
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  basewidth  = {.5em,0.4em},
  % columns  = flexible,
  columns    = fullflexible,
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting[
    language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
  ]{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with full flexible columns]

### Summary

- Instead of Computer Modern fonts I would use Latin Modern fonts, because they provide more font variants including bold.
- If the source code contains some kind of tables and the vertical alignment is important, a mono-spaced font with adjusted `basewidth` can be used:

  ```
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    basewidth={0.5em,0.5em},
  }
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  ```
- If the source code only requires indented lines as vertical alignment, a variable width typewriter font can be used:

  ```
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    % basewidth={0.5em,0.4em}, % for other columns settings
    columns=fullflexible,
  }
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
  ```

  This also decreases the line lengths, an advantage, if the code contains many long lines that would not fit in the available space of the line.

Comment: Heiko: Insanely great answer. Thanks for the followup!

Comment: Thanks a lot for `basewidth`, that's the parameter I was looking for.