# How to change fontsize in lstlisting without losing bold syntax highlighting?

Tags: listings, fontsize, bold

If I load the listing package to set nice code and change the font size (like suggested there: [Shrinking monospace style for listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33020/shrinking-monospace-style-for-listings-package)), I lose the syntax highlighting, because the font does not get bold anymore.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language={[Sharp]C},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny
}

\begin{lstlisting}
  int a = 5;
  //int should be bold, it's not.
  //commenting out basicstyle makes it bold, but to big
\end{lstlisting}
```

Is there some way to change the font size of listings without losing code highlighting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found the answer myself by trial-and-error:

```
basicstyle=\tiny
```

So you don't have to overwrite the font family, contrary to what the answer in the linked question suggested.

Comment: The standard monospaced font (Computer Modern Typewriter) has no bold variant. If you load `\usepackage{lmodern}`, then you'll get boldface also with `\ttfamily`.