# How to prevent the source code overflow over the frame in a listing?

Tags: listings, framed

I am trying to ident my source code in a frame using the listing package. An example code is given below:

```
\documentclass[article]{llncs}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[english]{varioref}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{RoyalBlue}}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[rulecolor=\color{black},frame=single,label={lst:dir},caption= example code that overflows the frame]

sssssssss sssss sssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssss

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The problem is some part of the code(letter "s") overflows the frame. I would really appreciate it if someone can suggest any solution for this problem. Please note that I don't want to use linebreaks or any thing similar. In fact I don't want to disturb my code at any cost!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If the source code alignments are not much of an issue, the following decreases the lines widths `columns=fullflexible` together with a variable-sized typewriter font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont\small\color{blue},
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  frame=single,
]
sssssssss sssss sssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssss
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

For more details and examples, see my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124710/16967) to a similar question.

> [image: Result]

### Smaller font sizes

Instead of `\small` smaller font sizes could be used:

`\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, `\tiny`.

See "[The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)", "Table 6.2: Font sizes".

### Option `linebreaks` – answer to an earlier version of the question

Option `breaklines` allows line breaks in source code listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  breaklines,
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  frame=single,
]
sssssssss sssss sssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssss
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use breaklines it will make my code difficult to understand. Is there any way to increase the frame width?

Comment: You will sooner or later hit the page border. You can try `columns=flexible` or even `columns=fullflexible` with variable-width typewriter font (`\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}`). Or decrease the font size. And the line lengths of the source file should be limited.

Comment: I am using \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{blue}} is there a font size smaller than "small"? I tried footnotesize even it didn't help.

Comment: @pss Due to the way the default fonts work (actually, this may be across the system), setting them even to `\tiny` won't change the width as much as you'd like it to.  Good code should also wrap to around 80 characters; there is never any reason it cannot.  (Edit: almost never.)

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks, the tiny option worked! but now the font is too small to read. Is there a font size option between small and tiny. ;-)

Comment: @pss I would *really* recommend breaking your code up into readable segments, but a full list of font sizes (along with some other *great* information as a general reference) is available at the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text).

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks for the reference! The \scriptsize option solved my problem. If you put your above comment as an answer then I'll select it as a selected answer. :-)  Else I'll answer it my self. :P

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks for the suggestion, but using \fontfamily{lmvtt} option doesn't retains the whitespaces and tabs in my source code. As a result I have to edit the source code.

Comment: @pss I'm glad I could help, but this question already had an answer here (hence the duplicate).  No more answers are needed.